# Remove border attribute from Pin It Button image to pass HTML5 validation

Tags: plugins, validation, html5

I am using the Pinterest "Pin It" Button plugin http://pinterestplugin.com which uses this code on my blog pages:

```
<img border="0" class="pib-count-img" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" />
```

`border="0"` is causing my blog to fail HTML5 validation. I keep getting the error: 'The border attribute is obsolete. Consider specifying img { border: 0; } in CSS instead.'

How can I remove the `border` attribute from the image used for the Pin It button so that my blog pages pass HTML5 validation?

Comment: @G.M. Hi, its http://pinterestplugin.com/

Comment: Sorry, this is a commercial plugin, it means we can't see the code, and without seeing the code it's not possible help you. Ask to plugin support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is behind a paywall  but assuming that is follows the [free version](http://wordpress.org/plugins/pinterest-pin-it-button/) fairly closely, [that attribute appears to be hard-coded](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/pinterest-pin-it-button/trunk/inc/public-display-functions.php#L132) and I don't see a filter.

That is a lot of code to dig through and it would be easy to miss something, but I don't think you can alter that without hacking the plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I hack the plugin to remove this small bit of invalid code?

Comment: You would edit the plugin source code. The link posted should guide you to where. ___But don't.___ It is a headache. Every time you update you will have to redo the work. Contact the plugin support and push them make the change.